# Javascript using local storage to save and retrieve table id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a MVC view that loads a table, and then when a link is clicked on the first table another table that is inside a different view loads.  I want to be able to higlight the rows for the second table that loads on click of a link in the first table.  It has been suggested to me that I use local storage to do this.  I'm not exactly sure how to grab the id of the second table using local storage.  Can anyone walk me through this.  Here is a sample I've made to show you what I'm trying to do.

1st view
table with click event that loads 2nd table

2nd view 
2nd table with table that has id instantTable

Here is what I am trying to do with the Javascript but it's not working

I have this in my 2nd view

```
<script>    
    var table = document.getElementById("instantTable")
    localStorage.setItem('table');
</script>
```

Then in my first view I have two links one with the class chargeback, and the other with class retroactive. Here is my jquery.

```
 $('#chargeback').on('click', function () {
        var result = localStorage.getItem("table");
        result.addClass('highlighted')
    });

    $('#retroactive').on('click', function () {
        var result = localStorage.getItem("table");
        result.addClass('highlighted')
    });
```

If more code is needed please let me know.  I'm trying to keep it simple.

Comment: can you please explain this  : **I want to be able to higlight the rows for the second table that loads on click of a link in the first table**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing an argument for `setItem()`. What you are looking to do is `localStorage.setItem("table", table)`. First parameter is the key with which you can grab the data from the local storage later and the second one is the actual data you want to save. The variable table must contain a string otherwise you need to convert it to a string because as far as i'm aware local storage can only save strings.

Comment: Dr. GIT I think that answers my question.  I'm going about this the wrong way.  Thank you.